# Find these conditional probabilitiy f(x|Y<=y)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

[image]Here a=2 and b=1 and it asks me that f(x|Y<=y) Can you help me about how to find?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some hints (this is one of the approaches):

- First apply Bayes rule
  $$f_X(x|Y\leq y)=\frac{P(Y\leq y|X=x)f_X(x)}{P(Y\leq y)}$$
- In order to find $P(Y\leq y|X=x)$, you can use the joint distribution (given that $1\leq x\leq 3)$ already:
  $$P(Y\leq y|X=x)=\int_2^y k x^{a+1}y^{b+1}dy$$
- You can find $P(Y\leq y)$ as well using the joint distribution similar to above.

Note that you'll also need to find $k$ in the end with the normalization property of the joint density.

Comment: why do we need fX(x|Y≤y) ? Can't we use only f(x|Y≤y) ?

Comment: $f_X(x|Y\leq y)$ is the same as $f(x|Y\leq y)$ in your notation. The former is a better notation.

Comment: then if it would say F(x|Y<=Y), is the way same again?

Comment: @mathh34556 $F$ typically denotes CDF, so $F_X(x|Y\leq y)=F(x|Y\leq y)$ in your notation.